# Kafka Configuration and kafka-node consumer issues

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-node

Hi I'm facing certain issues on Apache Kafka,

**Kafka Configuration**:
I'm using the **Kafka** latest version-v3.4.0. In Every version of Kafka config, there be a limit on the setup file, server.properties.I'm using these config on production.
**num.network.threads=3000**
**num.io.threads=5000**
These threads count can't raised over a certain limit of above 8000 in server.The Ulimit set - 65535 and also the network port range increased accordingly.
If I raised over the certain limit, it shows error like this.

**Error screenshot : **

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqxYT.png)

---

**Kafka Consumer**

And also I'm using the **kafka-node** package for **producing** and **consuming** the data, in that case sometimes the consumer file become Idle, no data receives from the consumer, but that data offset stored in the topic by the producer.

And also I configuring the mechanism of non-committed offsets from kafka will sends the data concurrently in a active queue to the receiver(consumer), once committed it will acknowledged by the **kafka-node** package

I'm trying to use the kafka as high streaming for that I needed kafka server must accepts the maximum inputs which I mentioned in the configuration setup, Next I know the reason for the kafka-node consumer package be idle for certain time and also missing offsets commits acknowledgement.

Comment: `kafka-node` is no longer maintained